# How to append a condition value to an empty vector?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to compare values and then, based on a result, append them to my empty vector. For some reason, my vector is always NULL while condition works:

```
dif <- c()


ifelse(10 > 5, 
       append(dif, "2"),
       append(dif, "error")
)


dif
```

Comment: I suspect you want to use `if(10 > 5) ... else ...` not `ifelse()` . The latter is used for vectorised operations like `ifelse(1:10 > 5, 1, 0)`

Comment: Thank you. No in fact I am trying to create a new vector that would contain difference values depending on what is greater in another vector: ```dif <- c()
ifelse(both$FC.black > both$FC.white, 
       append(dif, both$FC.black/both$FC.white),
       append(dif, 0/both$FC.black)
       )
dif``` \n The above code does the job but my empty vector is always empty

Comment: Okay, that is `ifelse` then, but `append` isn't needed. Try to assign afterwards `dif <- ifelse(both$FC.black > both$FC.white, both$FC.black/both$FC.white, 0)` - the last `0/both$FC.black` is always `0` so you can simplify that part too.

Comment: `ifelse` should never be used top-level, it should always be on the RHS of an assignment. Perhaps `dif <- append(dif, ifelse(cond, yes, no))`?

Comment: @thelatemail - Thanks a lot, that solved the problem. I just wonder why append is not required. Since in python, I suppose, that would be the first simplest idea to grow the list. I even thought to create a foreach loop for this, but it looks like it's way more simple. Thank you again.

Comment: @Lara - common R approaches rely primarily on vectorisation and functions, not explicit loops. As a rule, if you want to add 10 items to an output list, generate the 10 items from a single function call, and then assign the entire chunk at once. Growing objects via multiple `append`s or `<-` assignments will usually be more complex and often slower to run on large data.